# How to use DRY principal to organize and use a few classes that are interchangeable in Laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel, repository, dry

Sorry for the vague title. Let's say I provide a service that requires notifications to be sent to users when something happens related to a new blog post. They can have three options: SMS, automated voice call, or email. When they make a new post, the MySQL row will indicate which of the three types they chose.

Each option will need to trigger different events. For example, for email I'll need to use a `EmailRepository` that connects to the Mailchimp API to send an email when their post gets published, edited, or commented on. If SMS, I'll need to use a `SmsRepository` that uses Twilio when the same events happen, and the same idea with voice calls. So the controller that acts on these will need to choose the right path to take.

I'm not sure how to implement this: what I should reuse for each repository (because many functions can be the same, like send(), but each API works drastically differently), whether or not I should use a single interface for all of them, whether or not to use a single class while injecting different dependencies depending on the notification type chosen, etc. Does an example exist on how to set up something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the strategy pattern:

Personally, id create a class to handle notification calls, then just pass ('notification-content', 'method of delivery') from your controller to your notifications class which should implement a strategy pattern encapsulating the content to the notification channel.